# Can 2 users remote into a Windows 7 Ultimate box at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Can 2 users remote into a Windows 7 Ultimate box at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, same license as previous versions; but VNC still works.

Comment: +1.  Agree.  License details can be had at http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/useterms/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No.  They all support only one connection to the console only.   ONLY the server versions of Windows support multiple RDP sessions simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Not officially.

But there is a way to enable it in XP and Vista (and probably 7 too) by using a modified termsrv.dll. Google "concurrent remote desktop".

Comment: Of course this violates the license terms, and could land you in hot water.