# Multiple User login on the same local host -- TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localhost, visual-studio

We have Visual Studio on our server P.C. and we have created multiple user accounts on the server.
Now, when we run the same project from multiple accounts, and host them on local host, when one user logs in with some account ID, Password, the other user which has already signed in by some different account, logs off automatically.
Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: What OS is the server running?  Are the users logging in via RDP?

Comment: Windows 7 ... yupp, remote desktop protocol

Comment: @Azzy - Have you verfied this isn't simple a configuration settings problem?

Comment: @Ramhound

yes there is nothing wrong with the configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows client editions (like Windows 7) only allow one RDP session at a time.

If you need multiple RDP sessions concurrently then buy a Windows Server OS and enable terminal/remote desktop services (RDS), and/or perhaps check out:

- [Can 2 users remote into a Windows 7 Ultimate box at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/64586/can-2-users-remote-into-a-windows-7-ultimate-box-at-the-same-time/)
- [How to enable multiple logon remote desktop in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/64171/how-to-enable-multiple-logon-remote-desktop-in-windows-7)

Comment: I dont have a problem in giving remote access to multiple users to the same system. I have created many users with the administrative rights on that system and all can simultaneously use the system with their account provided to them. The problem occurs while hosting the Visual Studio Project via TFS. If one person logs on, the other persons TFS logs off.

Comment: @Azzy - IMO Techie007 answer does answer the question (what is written in the OP)! I think you should make this clear in your OP (how VS is related).